# Map from source objects to destination object and its collection of subobjects

Tags: json, automapper

I am trying to map objects but it's not really working well.

I have source object with structure:

```
Object Prod
{
     object<type1> Attribute (this object has fields field A,field B etc);
     List<type2> Species;
}
```

my destination object:

```
Object C
{
    field A,
    field B
    List<type3> subs
}
```

There is a mapping between type1 and object C and mapping between type2 and type3. However type3 subs list is always empty as there needs to be a map between object prod species and subs (which is collection).
How to map values from source to destination sub object collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Prod
{
    public Type1 Attribute;
    public List<Type2> Species;
}

public class C
{
    public int A;
    public string B;
    public List<Type3> Subs;
}

public class Type1
{
    public int A;
    public string B;
}

public class Type2
{
    public int C;
}

public class Type3
{
    public int D { get; set; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<Prod, C>()
    .ForMember(d => d.A, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Attribute.A))
    .ForMember(d => d.B, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Attribute.B))
    .ForMember(d => d.Subs, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Species));

Mapper.CreateMap<Type2, Type3>().ForMember(d => d.D, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.C));

var prod = new Prod
{
    Attribute = new Type1 { A = 1, B = "1" },
    Species = new List<Type2> { new Type2 { C = 2 }, new Type2 { C = 3 } }
};

var c = Mapper.Map<C>(prod);
```